# Strategy.orders not at the limit price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have modified this to a strategy
https://www.tradingview.com/script/ZpONAzhm-ORB-with-Price-Targets/

And im trying to make strategy orders at specific time of day, with a triggerprice of the high and lows of the orbs, but they dont fill at the correctly

```
...
    if is_first
        orbHighPrice := high
        orbLowPrice := low
        inBreakout := false
    else
        orbHighPrice := orbHighPrice[1]
        orbLowPrice := orbLowPrice[1]
    if high > orbHighPrice and in_session
        orbHighPrice := high
    if low < orbLowPrice and in_session
        orbLowPrice := low
...



var bool TradedToday = false
if timeframe.change("D")
    TradedToday := false

int ordertime = time(timeframe.period, "0330-0431:1234567")

//Short orders
if not TradedToday and ordertime and inTradeWindow
    strategy.order("Enter Long", strategy.long, limit=orbHighPrice)
    TradedToday := true
//STOPLOSS
if ta.cross(close, orbHighPrice + (orbRange * -0.5))
    strategy.close("Enter Long")
//TAKE PROFIT
if ta.cross(close, orbHighPrice + (orbRange * +1.0))
    strategy.close("Enter Long")

//Long orders
if not TradedToday and ordertime and inTradeWindow
    strategy.order("Enter Short", strategy.short, limit=orbLowPrice)
    TradedToday := true
//STOPLOSS
if ta.cross(close, orbLowPrice + (orbRange * +0.5))
    strategy.close("Enter Short")
//TAKE PROFIT
if ta.cross(close, orbLowPrice + (orbRange * -1.0))
    strategy.close("Enter Short")
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us how you define orbHighPrice ?

Comment: Its in the link above as I just edited a script into a strategy, but its edited into the original post now

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just realized I have to use stop=orbLowPrice instead of limit